# Azure App service smb access support (not azure files)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

Third party smb server running in onprem and cloud (Not azure files).

Does Azure App service support mounting smb access (read/write) for Linux container?

Can we use it for production for long running jobs like scanning files in smb mount?

Answer (score -1):

Access to SMB port's are disabled from Azure App Service

> Regardless of address, applications cannot connect to anywhere using ports 445, 137, 138, and 139. In other words, even if connecting to a non-private IP address or the address of a virtual network, connections to ports 445, 137, 138, and 139 are not permitted.
> -- https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#restricted-outgoing-ports

Even using Hybrid Connection's are blocked.

> Thanks for asking question! No, you cannot access on-premises file share from Azure App Service using Hybrid connection.
> -- SnehaAgrawal-MSFT
> -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/189699/can-we-access-on-premises-file-share-from-azure-ap.html

Comment: This is not true for Linux containers on App Service. 445 is not blocked at all when using Linux container.